# How to calculate absolute height of my dropdown

Tags: apache-flex

I have many dropdowns in my flex application. Now I want to set rowCount property so that as many rows as possible so there is less scrolling when see the dropdown items.
The flex application was running on a popup window. So I think I have to know the distance from dropdown to bottom border of window, and then calculate what number should be for the rowCount. Like Height/per row height.

As I known, the dropdown.y is the relative y coordinate of itself. But my dropdown has many parent UI layout component, and also I have many dropdowns, it is hard to calculate one by one. So do you know some effiency solution for my problem? Or you have other way to get the rowCount?

Answer (score 0):

while in your dropdown class:

```
var globalPoint:Point = this.localToGlobal(new Point(0,this.y));

trace("dropdown global Y = "+globalPoint.y);
```